# Special Relativity - Momentum Calculation

Tags: special-relativity, momentum

Recently I have been reading Berkeley Physics Course - Mechanics. In Chapter 12 (page 350 - 352), author gave a very good example that original definition of momentum $P = mv$ is not working by showing the y-axis' total momentum is not conserved before and after collision. Because:

$$-Mv'_y(1) + Mv'_y(2) \neq Mv_y'(1) - Mv_y'(2)$$

where
$$v_y'(1) = {v_y\over 1+{V^2\over c^2}}\left(1 - {V^2 \over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}$$
$$v_y'(2) = {v_y\over \left(1-{V^2\over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}$$

[image]

I continued to read the book and learnt that the corrected definition should be $P = \gamma mv$.

Here comes my question. I now tried to use the $P = \gamma mv$ to go back to the case mentioned above in the hope that it could yield a conservation in y-axis.

$$ {-M\over \left(1-{v_y'(1)^2 + v_x'(1)^2 \over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}v_y'(1) +  {M\over \left(1-{v_y'(2)^2 + v_x'(2)^2 \over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}v_y'(2) = {M\over \left(1-{v_y'(1)^2 + v_x'(1)^2 \over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}v_y'(1) -  {M\over \left(1-{v_y'(2)^2 + v_x'(2)^2 \over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}v_y'(2)$$

But very unfortunately they don't equal, since
$${M\over \left(1-{v_y'(1)^2 + v_x'(1)^2 \over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}v_y'(1) \neq  {M\over \left(1-{v_y'(2)^2 + v_x^{'}(2)^2 \over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}v_y'(2)$$

The left side contains $v_x'(1)$ which is something I am not able to eliminate, while the right side $v_x'(2) = 0$.
So I'm wondering what's wrong with my deduction. Is my understanding about the y-axis momentum wrong or purely calculation mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer by myself.

What really matters is that the $\pmb v_1$ in the numerator and $v_2^2$ in the denominator is different.
$$p = {m\pmb v_1\over \left(1-{v_2^2\over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}$$
The $\pmb v_1$ is actually the velocity of the particle in the given reference frame. This is easy to understand.

The $v_2$ is something however a bit tricky. In the book, it is mentioned that it's the speed of the particle relative to the reference frame in which $\Delta t$ is measured.

My understanding is that **$v_2$ is the only components of the speed that contributes to the difference of time measure (time dilation) in Lorentz Transformation**.

Therefore using the concepts above to solve the example mentioned, for sphere 1 $v_2$ = $v_x'(1)$ while for sphere 2 $v_2 = 0$

So it's easy to verify momentum of y-axis is conserved given that $${M\over \left(1-{v_x'(1)^2 \over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}v_y'(1) =  {M\over \left(1-{0^2 \over c^2}\right)^{1\over2}}v_y'(2)$$

using (omitting c) $${1\over \left(1-{{(u + v)^2 \over (uv)^2}}\right)^{1\over2}} = {(1 + uv)\over (1-{u^2})^{1\over2}(1-{v^2})^{1\over2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

In the original analysis, when you're using the non-relativistic momentum definition $P = mv$, you indeed encounter a problem with momentum conservation in the y-axis, which indicates that the classical momentum definition is not adequate in special relativity. This leads to the introduction of the corrected definition, where momentum is defined as $P = \gamma mv$ to account for relativistic effects.

Now, when you attempt to apply this corrected definition to the situation you've described, you should consider the full relativistic transformation of velocities in both the x-axis and y-axis. The transformations you've provided, $v_y'(1)$ and $v_y'(2)$, account for the y-component of velocity in the frame where the particle's velocity is $v$. However, you also need to consider the x-component of velocity ($v_x'(1)$ and $v_x'(2)$) in the transformations because, in the general case, both x and y components will change due to the relativistic effects.

Here's a corrected version of your momentum conservation equation using the relativistic transformation for both x and y components:

$
-\frac{M}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v_y'^2(1) + v_x'^2(1)}{c^2}}}v_y'(1) + \frac{M}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v_y'^2(2) + v_x'^2(2)}{c^2}}}v_y'(2) = \frac{M}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v_y'^2(1) + v_x'^2(1)}{c^2}}}v_y'(1) - \frac{M}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v_y'^2(2) + v_x'^2(2)}{c^2}}}v_y'(2)
$

(I hope my mathjax works)

Now, this equation should hold true for momentum conservation in both x and y directions when using the corrected definition of momentum. The differences in the x-components of velocity $v_x'(1)$ and $v_x'(2)$ in this equation account for the relativistic effects in the x-axis, and they will not necessarily cancel out as in the non-relativistic case.

Basically, the key issue in your incorrect deduction was not accounting for the relativistic transformation of the x-component of velocity. When using the corrected definition of momentum in special relativity, you should consider both the x and y components of velocity and apply the full Lorentz transformations to ensure momentum conservation in all directions.

Comment: Hi CarnotEngine,

Thanks for the detailed reply. 
I have considered the all the axis' velocities under relativistic effects so the equation is correct.

The only thing I am not able to explain is that why one side contains Vx and the other side contains Vx and Vy, if we try to separate the variables.

Comment: That is:
${{v_y^{'}(1)^2}\over {v_y^{'}(2)^2}} = {{(1-{v_y^{'}(1)^2 + v_x^{'}(1)^2 \over c^2})}\over {(1-{v_y^{'}(2)^2 + v_x^{'}(2)^2 \over c^2})}}$

The left side contains Vx but right side contains Vx and Vy.